# Highlight first table Cell, issues

Tags: ios

```
- (void) SelectFirstCell 
{

    NSIndexPath *indexPath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];

    [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES  scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom];
}
```

Hello, i have this very simple method that is supposed to highlight the first Table Cell, but it is not working, the method does get called, and the values do match, Row 0 inSection 0 does exist.

But it does not get highlighted ?

If it makes any difference it is a table created by the Tapku Calendar View

Its worth mentioning that i am very new to Obj C

Comment: That code should work. Are you sure that method is called? From where in your app do you call this?

Comment: Where are you calling this method from ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
[self.yourTableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
- (void) SelectFirstCell 
{
    NSIndexPath * firstElement = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];

        [self.tableView.delegate tableView:self.tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:firstElement];
        [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:firstElement animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop];
}
```

Hope it help!

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
   NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
  [tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:TRUE scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
  [[tableView delegate] tableView:tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```